# Hold For Observation

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the verb "*hold*" [here](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052702303376904579135732284488114):

> When in the hospital, more Medicare recipients are being ***held for observation*** rather than being formally admitted, a status that can leave them with big bills for items including rehabilitation services.

According to google searches, "*hold*", in the context of preventing someone from leaving a place, is normally used for police "*holding suspects*" or criminals "*holding hostages*".  So, is the usage of "hold" for hospital patients, specialty jargon?

Comment: I wouldn't call it jargon. The sentence simply means that patients are being kept to make sure they are alright, but this highly increases their debts.

Comment: 'held' can be used for any sort of delay. *"The items from the assembly line were held [back] for inspection."* See also ["put a hold on"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+hold+on)

Comment: Hold on a minute: What searches indicated those are "normal" usages of the word _hold_? What about _holding hands, holding secrets, holding cards, holding signs, holding classes, holding grudges, holding a trial, holding your ground, holding your breath_ or _holding your horses_? Maybe we should vote to put this question on hold...

Comment: @J.R.  I've just modified my question slightly.  Please re-read!

Answer (score 2):

"held for observation" is used in particular for psychiatric/psychological contexts. It means a period of time where the patient's health is monitored by health care providers to determine if there is a significant issue which mandates admission.  It means the patient generally cannot leave before the time period is up.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of 'hold for observation' is pretty much defined in the article

> Hospitals and doctors place patients on observation care to give doctors time to evaluate whether they require an inpatient stay.

So, yes, "hold for observation" has a meaning used specifically in hospitals. But, to my knowledge, a person being "held" for observation may voluntarily leave. Therefore "hold" here does not mean against one's will. This is similar to "We want to *keep* you here for observation." Again, only if you or someone who speaks for you legally  (for example, your parents or your power of attorney) agree.

The use in a psychiatric hospital setting is unknown to me. *Ie* I don't know when and if patients can be 'held' or 'kept' involuntarily.